# How to configure Burp Suite if system proxy is handled by websense and application can only be accessed through IE?

Tags: burp-suite

I need to capture a traffic of the application that is compatible only for IE browser, and the proxy server is handled by websense. Thus, system proxy can't be set.

Is it possible through Upstream Proxy server settings? If yes, what are the configuration specifications?

Answer (score 2):

We recommend you perform testing from a system that you have administrative control over, so you can set the proxy settings. This could be a virtual machine.

If that's not possible, you may be able to set the proxy directly in the registry. There's some information on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568502/ie-enable-disable-proxy-settings-via-registry).

You may still need to set an Upstream Proxy within Burp, depending on the setup of the network you're on.